# Appending values to two key defaultdict in python

Tags: python, list, defaultdict

From a text file, I am trying to append one following value as the value from the two previous values as the keys. Here is mt code:

```
# this is a sample file. The output that I would like is ["apple","orange"]
lines = "This is apple. This is orange".split() 
d = defaultdict(list)
d[("This", "is")] = list
for i, tokens in enumerate(lines):
    if "This" == lines[i] and "is" == lines[i+1]:
        d[(lines[i], lines[i+1])].append([lines[i+2]])
print d[("This", "is")]
```

But I get the error as shown below:

```
TypeError: `append() takes exactly one argument (0 given)` on `d[(lines[i], lines[i+1])].append([lines[i+2]])`
```

Could someone help ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following line assign `list` type itself, not a `list` instance.

```
d[("This", "is")] = list
```

Above line should be replaced with:

```
d[("This", "is")] = list()
```

or

```
d[("This", "is")] = []
```

or the line can be removed completely, because [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) will handle the case if there's no matching key in the dictionary.